# Activiti - Signal and Call Activity

Tags: workflow, activiti

Here is our Activiti (version 5.21) main diagram:
[image: diagram]
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <signal id="alertSignal" name="alert"></signal>
  <process id="Call" name="Call" isExecutable="true">
    <callActivity id="callactivity1" name="Call activity 1" calledElement="Call1">
      <extensionElements>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE1" target="VARIABLE1"></activiti:in>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE2" target="VARIABLE2"></activiti:in>
       </extensionElements>
    </callActivity>
    <callActivity id="callactivity2" name="Call activity 2" calledElement="Call2">
      <extensionElements>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE1" target="VARIABLE1"></activiti:in>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE2" target="VARIABLE2"></activiti:in>
      </extensionElements>
    </callActivity>
    <callActivity id="callactivity3" name="Call activity 3" calledElement="Call3">
      <extensionElements>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE1" target="VARIABLE1"></activiti:in>
    <activiti:in source="VARIABLE2" target="VARIABLE2"></activiti:in>
      </extensionElements>
    </callActivity>
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent2" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="callactivity1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="callactivity1" targetRef="callactivity2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="callactivity2" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="callactivity3" targetRef="endevent2"></sequenceFlow>
    <boundaryEvent id="boundarysignal1" name="Signal" attachedToRef="callactivity1" cancelActivity="true">
      <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="boundarysignal1" targetRef="callactivity3"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

And the first call activity:
[image: diagram 2]
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <signal id="alertSignal" name="alert"></signal>
  <process id="Call1" name="Call1" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="test-a" name="test-a">
      <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{VARIABLE1.allow(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <parallelGateway id="parallelgateway1" name="Parallel Gateway"></parallelGateway>
    <userTask id="test-b" name="test-b">
      <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{VARIABLE1.allow(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="test-a"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="test-a" targetRef="parallelgateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="test-b"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="test-b" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <intermediateThrowEvent id="signalintermediatethrowevent1" name="SignalThrowEvent">
      <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
    </intermediateThrowEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="signalintermediatethrowevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

The thing is that the variables "VARIABLE1" and "VARIABLE2" are not getting passed to the "Call activity 2", i guess there's something wrong with the boundary signal maybe ? Because they are getting passed to "Call Activity 1". Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know the variables are not being sent to Call Activity 2?
Are you injecting the variables on process startup?

I ask because if you are not initializing the process variables before you get to Called Activity 1, then they actually don't get passed into the sub process as variables, rather they are initialized on instantiation of the call activity 1 sub process.

Hence, if the variables dont exist on entry to the Call Activity 1, then there is no variable to pass into call activity 2

This should be a relatively easy unit test to create to demonstrate which would clear up any questions on your scenario.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Im initializing the variables on startup. Those variables are being saved on act_ru_variable for "Call Activity 1". But, after the signal, when "Call Activity 2" tries to use them, i get an error, cause they are not being passed.

Comment: Can you attach a unit test.
Be aware, if the variables are updated in Called Activity 1 prior to sending the signal, the updated values will not be available in called activity 2 as a called sub process exists in in its own execution context. 
But, with a nit test we should be able to see what is going on.

Comment: I implemented a client (simple java application using jdbc) with the objective of unit testing and it worked. So probably was something in our main project. Thanks!